# Cannot reach elm Tick action

Tags: signals, effects, elm, keyboard-input

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out here with Signals and Effects.

I'm looking into Signals/Effects and have been studying the-elm-architecture, particularly [example 8](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/master/examples/8/SpinSquare.elm#L45).

In this example (as I understand it), if you click on the shape(s) :

- a signal message is sent to the address along with the action
- the `SPIN` action is fired on update
- if he shape isn't currently animating, Tick is also called.

I'm trying to replicate the exact same flow (using similar code) but instead of clicking on a button and using the HTML package, I want to just send a signal using the spacebar.

In my code, the spacebar sends a Signal off to the `Punch` action. Just like example 8, I want to then also call `Tick` and update the `debounceState` in my model.

You'll see in my comments that I can reach my `Punch` action, but I don't seem to ever get to `Tick`.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116353/elm-effects-the-tick-function-apparently-never-get-called), but because I'm using a Keyboard Signal and not the elm StartApp, I don't think it applies.

If someone could explain why I'm not able to reach `Tick` in my example, I'd super appreciate it.

```
module Main (..) where

import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Time exposing (Time, second)
import Effects exposing (Effects)
import Keyboard


type alias DebounceState =
  Maybe
    { prevClockTime : Time
    , elapsedTime : Time
    }


type alias Model =
  { punching : Bool
  , count : Int
  , randomString: String
  , debounceState : DebounceState
  }


duration = second


-- MODEL


initialModel : ( Model, Effects Action )
initialModel =
  ( { punching = False
    , count = 0
    , randomString = ""
    , debounceState = Nothing
    }
  , Effects.none
  )


model : Signal ( Model, Effects Action )
model =
  Signal.foldp update initialModel (punch Keyboard.space)


-- ACTIONS


type Action
  = NoOp
  | Punch Bool
  | Tick Time


-- UPDATE


update : Action -> ( Model, Effects Action ) -> ( Model, Effects Action )
update action ( model, fx ) =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      ( model, Effects.none )

    Punch isPunching ->
      case model.debounceState of
        Nothing ->
          ( { model |
              punching = isPunching
              , count = model.count + 1 }, Effects.tick Tick )

        Just _ ->
          ( { model |
              punching = isPunching
              , count = model.count + 2 }, Effects.none )

    -- I don't seem to reach `Tick` at all
    -- You'll notice that I try to apply a value to `randomString` in the
    -- conditional to indicate where I end up
    Tick clockTime ->
      let
        newElapsedTime =
          case model.debounceState of
            Nothing ->
              0

            Just {elapsedTime, prevClockTime} ->
              elapsedTime + (clockTime - prevClockTime)
      in
        if newElapsedTime > duration then
          ( {model | randomString = "foo"} , Effects.none )
        else
          ( {model | randomString = "bar"} , Effects.tick Tick )


-- SIGNAL


punch : Signal Bool -> Signal Action
punch input =
  Signal.map Punch input


-- VIEW

view : ( Model, Effects Action ) -> Element
view model =
  show model


main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map view model
```

Paste that straight into [Try Elm](http://elm-lang.org/try).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tick` action is never fired because there is no port transferring `Effects` into `Tasks`. In the related Stack Overflow answer you posted, [`StartApp`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/latest/) is being used, so wiring up a port is easy.

Since you are not using `StartApp`, there's a few things you'll have to do manually. Right now, your `model` is only listening to the keyboard space signal. You'll need to wire up signal handling so your Effects go all the way back to firing your `update` function.

You'll need a mailbox to coordinate the signals.

```elm
actions : Signal.Mailbox (List Action)
actions =
  Signal.mailbox []
```

Notice that this mailbox is defined in terms of a List of Actions. That's one of the complicated parts about translating Effects to Tasks, and it is [explained here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-effects/latest/Effects#toTask).

Now you'll need a port that takes the second part of your `(Model, Effects Action)` tuple and translates that to a `Task`.

```elm
port effects : Signal (Task.Task Effects.Never ())
port effects =
  Signal.map (Effects.toTask actions.address << snd) model
```

That port will now send your `Tick` action to the mailbox, but we still haven't wired up your model to listen to both the keyboard space key and this new mailbox. To do that, we'll use `Signal.mergeMany`.

```elm
signals : Signal Action
signals =
  let
    singleAction list =
      case list of
        [] -> NoOp
        (a::_) -> a
  in
    Signal.mergeMany
      [ punch Keyboard.space
      , Signal.map singleAction actions.signal
      ]
```

The funny business going on in the `singleAction` function just gets us around the fact that `Effects.toTask` forces us to use a list of `Actions` rather that a single `Action`. Looking at the documentation, it is clear that we are safe just taking the first element off the list.

So now we have a signal that is triggered both by the keyboard space bar as well as the Tick action. The last part is to make the `model` listen to that signal instead of just the keyboard.

```elm
model : Signal ( Model, Effects Action )
model =
  Signal.foldp update initialModel signals
```

Comment: What an excellent answer. Thank you for your help and additional links